# Error while compiling with qmake, qt?

Tags: qt, qmake

I tried to write a simple qt application and I get this error when I try to compile it

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>

int main(int argv, char **args)
{
    QApplication app(argv, args);

    QTextEdit textEdit;
    textEdit.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

_

```
qmake file.cpp

/home/j/qtf.cpp:4: Extra characters after test expression.
/home/j/qtf.cpp:6: Extra characters after test expression.
/home/j/qtf.cpp:8: Extra characters after test expression.
/home/j/qtf.cpp:11: Extra characters after test expression.
```

Where is the error

Comment: Take a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-running.html. qmake takes one or more project files as input and not c++ source files.

Comment: qmake doesn't compile anything. It is used to generate makefiles (or project file skeletons for you to improve, if given `-project` argument).

Answer (score 3):

In order to compile your application you have to:

- Create a project file,
- Generate makefiles,
- Build the project.

To perform these steps simply invoke the corresponding commands:

```
qmake -project (generates project file)
qmake          (generates makefile)
make           (build the project)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what would be the name of the project file once I run qmake -project :)

Comment: I guess it will be the name of the directory your sources live in. You can rename it, if you want.